# Rake db:migrate and HTML generated not changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to RoR and building my first application. I used `rails generate scaffold` and created a table in database. Of course I did it wrong, wanted to make changes to the table, did it by rewriting the generated migration file. I think `rake db:migrate` works fine, because it's updating my schema, but there are no changes visible on the site. The view of the table didn't change, although the mechanism is different, I can't add anything now because it can't find the proper columns after I changed them. I have no idea how to fix it without rewriting the view files myself. Is it possible, I think I'm missing something?

Comment: You don't usually modify migration files, you just make another migration. Any particular reason you did it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can undo/destroy scaffold by `rails destroy scaffold scaffold_name` and then re-generate scaffold with the columns you added on migration file. FYI, editing migration files is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either you destroy the scaffolding that you've created with `rails destroy scaffold ModelName` or you change the views by hand. When you run `rake db:migrate` it won't do anything in the views.